# jquery make cloned element droppable

Tags: jquery, clone, drag

Iam having troubles making a cloned element droppable(). This code works for the original elements, but the cloned element in the end is not droppable anymore, what can I do?

```
$('.drop').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'dragHover',
});

$('.drag').draggable({
    helper: dragHelper,
});



function dragHelper( ) {

    var clone = $('.dragHelper');        
    return clone.clone().show();
}

$('.drop').clone(true,true).insertAfter('.drag');
```

See JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hakuch/h03zL206/

Answer (score 1):

Move the clone() call before making it droppable. The droppable setup is not being kept after the clone.

```
$('.drop').clone(true,true).insertAfter('.drag');

$('.drop').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'dragHover',
});

$('.drag').draggable({
    helper: dragHelper,
});



function dragHelper( ) {

    var clone = $('.dragHelper');        
    return clone.clone().show();
}
```

Comment: But shouldn't `.clone(true, true)` do the trick, like keeping the element setup?

Comment: It should, but there must be something in the jQuery UI droppable implementation that's linked to the first call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your approach is not working. Because passing both parameters to `clone` should do the job. However it doesn't. But you can make it work by just using `.clone()` and apply the `.droppable()` handler afterwards.

```
var clone = $('.drop').clone();
clone.droppable({
    hoverClass: 'dragHover'
});
clone.insertAfter('.drag');
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h03zL206/4/

Comment: mh yes this works in the test case, but in my more complex program it doesnt, I still don't get why but trying to figure out